# Erratic While Loop Results

Tags: php, while-loop

I created a while loop that produces random images for the user. Every time I load the page the while loop produces a random number of images. I would like for it to show 10 but it will produce anywhere from 3-10 images. I checked in the database and `user_id` is unique for every entry. I have no idea why it's doing this. What is wrong with the code? I'll also accept an answer that can point in a direction (tutorial link) to rewrite this code in a better way.

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM  `users` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 10");

$r = 1;

while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

    {   

$var_1 = $results_row['user_id']; 

    $getting_essentials = mysql_query("SELECT 

    `band_name`,`donated_money`,`donated_time` FROM `create_project` WHERE `user_id` = 

    $var_1");

    $getting_results = mysql_fetch_assoc($getting_essentials);

$bandsname = $getting_results['band_name'];

if (isset($bandsname) === true) {       

$donatedmoney = $getting_results['donated_money'];

$donated_time = $getting_results['donated_time'];   

$var_2 = username_from_user_id($var_1); 

$image_name = 'images/' . md5($var_2) . '_' . $var_1;       

    echo '<a href="' . $var_2 . '"><img src="' . $image_name . '" class="'.$r.'" 

    width="300" height="185"/></a>';

} 
$r++;
}

?>
```

Comment: If `user_id` is unique, then you won't need `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting the same erratic behavior though.

Comment: what is the purpose of $var_2 i mean where $var_2 is assigned.and $image_name it does not contain any image extension, the code produce something like 'images/jdgjkgdfkgf234/5'. so it should not show image.

Comment: You don't need two queries for this. Just combine them with a JOIN so you don't have to do the second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of *potential* problems.

First, what is `var_2`? It doesn't appear to be set anywhere.

Second, it appears that you will get as many images as there are unique user IDs in your table. This seems to me a bizarre way of trying to get ten images.

Third, the actual file names you're using for the images are built using the user ID. It may well be that not all the files exist.

A way to check that last point is to simply do a "View Source" operation in your browser.

It may be that you're always getting 123 images (assuming you have 123 distinct user IDs) but some of them don't exist.

As a low-level debugging exercise, you can insert code to echo debug statements (in HTML format) so you can see what's happening under the covers. This is often the quickest way to determine problems. In other words, pepper your code with things like:

```
$bandsname = $getting_results['band_name'];     # Existing line
echo 'bandsname is "' . $bandsname . '".<br>';  # new line
```

By doing that and examining the output, it'll make it a lot more obvious than trying to do static analysis on the code.

Comment: Sorry, this is what happens when I try to simplify the code on here. Let me show you the full code.

Comment: Thanks for the potential problems, I've fixed it but the errors are still shown. With what I want to do, randomly selecting and showing several images, I've figured this code is inappropriate and will work on a new solution.

Comment: Your debugging solutions are extremely helpful. What I've realized is that this code is bad and I'm going to rewrite it. Thanks for the help. I'll consider your solution as the answer, because it sets the tone for the answer that, "A rewrite is the better than fixing all these problems including these multiple Resource Id errors."

Answer (score 0):

The following post will provide a solution to your answer
http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: While it's good advice to not use `rand()` in this way, it's a _brave_ call on your part to say it'll fix _this_ problem.